# U.S. citizen wants a travel visa to China

Tags: visas, china

I am a U.S. citizen and have been invited to an event in Beijing, China. How long will it take me to get a visa to travel to China?

Answer (score 3):

The [visa processing times](http://www.china-embassy.org/eng/visas/fees/) listed in the Chinese embassy's web site are:

> Regular service: 4 business days
>
> Express service: 2-3 business days
>
> Rush service: 1 business day. Available only in extreme emergencies and subject to approval by the consular officer.
>
> Note:
>
> 1. The above processing time is average and for reference only. Some applications may require longer processing time that a pick-up date cannot be confirmed until notified by the Visa Office.